# How to change permission dialog UI in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

How to change permission alert UI on Flutter(Ios and Android)?

[image: click here to view alert]

Comment: I am not familiar with Flutter but i think you can not change the Permission dialog .. Its a System Dialog you have no control over it .. Dialog will be shown as per Android version . for instance Android 10 have a modified alert for location permission .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't change that, no modifications are allowed in both iOS and Android. What you can do is create your own dialog that matches this UI and show user the reason explaining why you need the permission in case they deny it. That's all you can do.