# How to remove permission request on start?

Tags: flutter, user-permissions

How can I remove the permission request on start of the app so I can request it on the page itself?

[image: Permission on start]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61284272/how-to-change-permission-dialog-ui-in-flutter

Check this answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of the plugins initializing the permissions.
make sure that your code does not call the camera plugin in the beginning.